# Ubuntu not detecting Headphones

Tags: sound, headphones

I have Windows, and I decided to install ubuntu as a dual boot.

Ubuntu is working great, but I still have a problem.

Ubuntu doesn't detect my headphones (of model logitech g332).

What I mean by that is that there is sound coming out of the inbuilt speakers. USB cables are also working, since I can use another keyboard, mouse, etc. Ubuntu doesn't even detect the headphones.
I also tried with earphones, and the result is the same.
I am using Jack sockets to plug in my earphones/headphones. I tried using different sockets, but the result is the same.

The builtin speakers are still playing sound when the earphones/headphone are plugged in. 
When using lsusb, with and without my earphones/headphone, I get the same result (meaning it is not even detected).
Output with and without :

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 3938:1031 MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:1866 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N-KEY Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My version of Linux (output from "cat /proc/version" command) :

```
Linux version 5.3.0-41-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-020) (gcc version 9.2.1 20191008 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2)) #33-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 14 17:26:47 UTC 2020
```

Everything works fine on Windows.

My computer is a GU502G (an ASUS Zephyrus laptop).

I searched for some time, and tried different things :

- letting my computer sleep some time, and waking it up
- reinstalling pulseaudio / alsamixer
- adding to /ect/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf the line

  options snd-hda-intel model=MODEL

with MODEL being the model.

Here are some information :

```
=17: PCI 1f.3: 0403 Audio device
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: nS1_.meQMPO27pOD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1f.3
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa348 "Cannon Lake PCH cAVS"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1043 "ASUSTeK Computer Inc."
  SubDevice: pci 0x1881 
  Revision: 0x10
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xa5418000-0xa541bfff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xa5100000-0xa51fffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 126 (741 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A348sv00001043sd00001881bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: snd_soc_skl is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_soc_skl"
  Driver Info #2:
    Driver Status: sof_pci_dev is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe sof_pci_dev"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

Nothing new seems to be detected when using alsamixer.
When going into my audio settings (using gnome-control-center), only the inbuilt speakers appear and can be selected.

It seems that a similar question has already been posted here : https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=306891
However, no fix was found.

My friend thinks that it could be because I have new components (since I have a new computer), and that the reason could be because drivers (or something like that) for ubuntu where not finished yet.

What do you think about that ? Do you have an idea on how to fix this issue?

Thank you for reading!
(By the way, I am a noob concerning Ubuntu, so explain slowly please)

Comment: What type of headphones are you using? What do you see under the sound settings? can you provide the output of lsusb?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: I added other informations, like trying with my earpods, my version of Ubuntu, and the output of lsusb. 
If you want some other information, don't hesitate to say which ones and how to get them. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

For those searching:
The headphones has started working correctly suddenly.
This must be thanks to a driver update that happened a while back.

Comment: You correctly displayed the Linux kernel version in the question. You may show what Linux version is running now. If it has changed then you are probably correct about the driver update.